# Postgres access from custom dll with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have dll with data context

```
using rmclibrary.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace rmclibrary
{
    public class RmcContext : DbContext
    {
        public RmcContext() : base("RmcContext")
        {

        }
 public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
// ...and etc
    }

}
```

In the Brand class I have  Check method

```
public class Brand
    {
        [Key]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string UID1C { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Prefix { get; set; }

    public void Check()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nachalo");
            using (var dc = new RmcContext())
            {

                var k = new Brand();
                k.Name = "trrr";
                k.Prefix = 4444;

                dc.Brands.Add(k);
                dc.SaveChanges();

            }

        }

    }
```

Below app.config

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>    
    <providers>      
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />      
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="RmcContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123456789;Database=rmctest;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Migration and Updating  going  with out  ani problrms

this  dll I'm add in new console project  and  try use Check method

```
using rmclibrary.Model;
using System;

    namespace DatabaseWorker
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start");
                var z = new Brand();
                z.Check();            
            }
        }
    }
```

It is  stuck on this line u`sing (var dc = new RmcContext())`
and  after couple minute give  error :
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Comment: Have you tried removing all the references to SQL Server in your app.config?  The fact that your exception is SqlException coming from System.Data.SqlClient namespace tells me that your context is trying to connect to a SQL Server database since that is the provider for it.   I would wager that your context is not trying to use your Postgres database.

Comment: update app.config
  same error

Comment: Is this app.config for the DLL or for the console app?

Comment: This is for dll

Comment: That would be your issue then.  The settings will get passed through from your calling application and used.  Put the settings in the console app.config and see if that fixes the problem.